# Celery : Received unregistered task of type

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

its my first time using celery and I'm having trouble executing some simple functions. I run `celery -A IrisOnline worker/beat -l info` and it gives me the unregistered type error. Heres the structure of my app:

```
-Iris-Online
 -IrisOnline
   -__init__.py
   -tasks.py
   -celery_app.py
   -settings.py
 -templates
 -manage.py
```

inside **settings.py**:

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Manila'

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'execute_1_min': {
        'task': 'celery_app.printthis',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),
        'args': (16,16)
    },
}
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("IrisOnline.celery_app","IrisOnline.tasks")
```

**tasks.py**

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks',backend="redis://localhost:6379")

@app.task
def print_this():
    print("something")
```

**celery_app.py**

```
from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'IrisOnline.settings')

app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')

# Using a string here means the worker don't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def printsomething(self):
    print('this')
```

Comment: What happens when you do `app.autodiscover_tasks()` instead of `app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)`?

Comment: yeah it seems like my problem was in including the taskts. i solved it by adding the include='app.tasks' parameter in my app=Celery(...)